# Reduce space below a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, floats

Due to the page limit, I now wish to reduce the blank space right after a figure (a TikZ drawing).

I personally find it too big.

Below is my MWE. How may I fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage{tikz} % for TikZ drawing

\begin{document}
\lipsum
The system architecture is shown in Figure~\ref{fig:systemarchitecture}.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=0.95*\columnwidth, anchor=west}, font=\small]
\node[block, minimum width=0.9*\columnwidth, minimum height = 3cm, fill=yellow, opacity=1, text opacity=1](phone) at (0,0){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{System Architecture}
    \label{fig:systemarchitecture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add `[htb]` to `\begin{figure}[htb]`, the figure will look nice. If you still want to reduce the space, put `\usepackage[belowskip=-10pt]{caption}` in the preamble. Change `-10pt` to suit your need.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. Merely adding `[htb]` looks pretty much the same. So I am trying to use `\usepackage[belowskip=-10pt]{caption}`, but `! LaTeX Error: Command \caption@ContinuedFloat already defined`.

Comment: If you use `[htb]` the figure is properly placed (i.e., after it is mentioned in text). Regarding the error, you have something else. Your mwe above works for me. Please add more details.

Comment: @HarishKumar  my full packages are http://pastie.org/8533217  I guess it is some sort of conflicts there.

Comment: With your entire preamble, it works and I don't get the error you mentioned above.

Comment: @HarishKumar  Oh! Then I guess it is due to the document class \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} maybe they have something similar already defined there?

Answer (score 3):

An quick fix without using package is to add a negative length to

```
`\abovecaptionskip{-<dimension>}` and `\belowcaptionskip{-<dimension>}`
```

which adjust the vertical space before and after the caption, as shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage{tikz} % for TikZ drawing
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{-10pt}  %%%%
\addtolength\belowcaptionskip{-20pt}  %%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum
The system architecture is shown in Figure~\ref{fig:systemarchitecture}.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=0.95*\columnwidth, anchor=west}, font=\small]
\node[block, minimum width=0.9*\columnwidth, minimum height = 3cm, fill=yellow, opacity=1, text opacity=1](phone) at (0,0){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{System Architecture}
    \label{fig:systemarchitecture}
\end{figure}
\end{document
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the `caption` package and reduce the skip with `belowskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\usepackage{tikz} % for TikZ drawing
\usepackage[belowskip=-20pt]{caption} % reduce/increase the skip after the figure with belowskip

\begin{document}
\lipsum
The system architecture is shown in Figure~\ref{fig:systemarchitecture}.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum width=0.95*\columnwidth, anchor=west}, font=\small]
\node[block, minimum width=0.9*\columnwidth, minimum height = 3cm, fill=yellow, opacity=1, text opacity=1](phone) at (0,0){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{System Architecture}
    \label{fig:systemarchitecture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Just read the comments after posting, this solutions was already posted.